# How to exclude some fields in ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have `Account` model. At the other side I have model `Student`. They Have a relationship, indeed I wanted to manage different types of users.

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    class Gender(models.TextChoices):
        MALE = "M", "Male"
        FEMALE = "F", "Female"
        OTHER = "O", "Other"
        UNSET = "U", "Unset"

    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email",
                              max_length=100, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="first name", max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="last name", max_length=40)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=Gender.choices, default=Gender.UNSET)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(
        verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    @property
    def is_student(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'student')

    @admin.display(boolean=True)
    def is_student_display(self):
        return self.is_student

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

`Student`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

I need to serializes Student model rather than Account model. But I need to to have field `user`. So I did:

```
class StudentBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student 
        fields = ("user",)
        depth = 2
```

As you may guess, this returns all the fields, like `password`, `is_admin`, `is_staff` so on.

How can I exclude some fields while `depth=2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use instead of depth, multiple serializers and inside these ones, exclude the not important fields:

```
class StudentBaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    user = UserCustomizedSerializer(many = True)

    class Meta:
        model = Student 
        fields = ("user",)
```